# Warning: (vsim-7) Failed to open readmem file "mem_content_01.dat" in read mode

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I am trying to run a test simulation in ModelSim and am getting the error in the title. I have double checked and the file is in the same location as my project and the names match just fine. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? 
Please let me know if there is some part of the code that you need to see or anything like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah got it! Okay so ModelSim is weird. I had to place the .dat file in the directory above work so that it would work. Apparently it shouldn't be in the same place as my verilog code.

Comment: It has to be in the current working directory (i.e. where you start ModelSim from).